# While loop and switch keep repeating

Tags: java

Write a program that asks the user to enter a year. The program should then indicate the type of year it is based on the Chinese Zodiac.

You will need:

A scanner object for input
Input validation: Make sure the year entered is positive! (Use a while loop for this part.)
A variable to store the year entered
A switch statement to select the appropriate zodiac sign

A sample of the output is shown below:
Enter a year: -89
Enter anno domini (AD) years please!
Re-enter the year: 1989
The year 1989 is the year of the snake

When I run the code and type in a year, the code keeps running and repeating itself. How do I make it so it just prints once?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChineseZodiac {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a year: ");
        year = in.nextInt();

        while (year != 0)
        {
            switch (year % 12) 
            {
            case 0: 
            {
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Monkey"); 
            break;
            }

            case 1: 
            {   
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Rooster"); 
            break;
            }

            case 2: 
            {   
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Dog"); 
            break;
            }

            case 3: 
            {
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Pig"); 
            break;
            }

            case 4:
            {
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Rat"); 
            break;
            }

            case 5: 
            {   
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Ox"); 
            break;
            }

            case 6: 
            {
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Tiger"); 
            break;
            }

            case 7: 
            {
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Rabbit"); 
            break;
            }

            case 8: 
            {   
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Dragon"); 
            break;
            }

            case 9: 
            {   
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Snake"); 
            break;
            }

            case 10: 
            {   
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Horse"); 
            break;
            }

            case 11: 
            {
                System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Sheep"); 
            break;
            }
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Use following code in while then user press 0 it will exit otherwise ask and give rsult Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a year: ");
    year = in.nextInt();

Comment: Of course a while loop keeps repeating. That's the point of it. And unless you change the year variable to 0 or break out of it, it will keep looping.

Comment: `"How do I make it so it just prints once?"` - By removing the loop.  The *purpose* of a loop is to repeat something.

Answer (score 0):

The while requires that year is equal to 0 to end, but the problem is that you never change the year value inside the loop, so it will just keep repeating.

Answer (score 0):

> ....the code keeps running and repeating itself. How do I make it so
>   it just prints once?..

You have `while`, it will keep looping until `year=0`

```
while (year != 0)
{
```

should be

```
if (year != 0)
{
```

Also, no point of having `case 0` as it will never execute. Below line of code is simply useless.

```
case 0: 
        {
            System.out.println("The year " + year + " is the year of the Monkey"); 
        break;
        }
```